# Using object Operator with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys am new to php development  and i have seen a code like

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
if ($link) {
    die('cannot connect:'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("chat", $link);

if ($SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$message = $_POST['message'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (message) VALUES ('$message')");
}

$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC');
enter code here

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
$posts[] = array(
    'message' => $row -> message
    );
}
```

Am confused of what `$row->message` means??..is it same as `$row['message']`..

Hope you guys can help Thanks

Comment: Its storing `message` as a property of the row.  Same as saying `$this->message = "HELLO"` and then `[object] $thing = new ObjectName(); return $thing->message;`

Comment: @TJB4rn3s sorry i have reedited my qus ..it acts like a key..

Comment: @TJB4rn3s actually is $row->message means fetching column or fetching $message variable ?

Comment: You are fetching the [results](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) as an object.  If you use mysqli_fetch_array($query) it will fetch the results as an array.  So instead of accessing the results like $row["arrayKey"] you are accessing the "message" value from the database as a property of the row... so $row->message (that is how you access properties of objects in PHP)

Comment: @TJB4rn3s so is $row['message'] same as $row->message ??

Comment: it should have the same value... yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch mysql_query result inform of array / object

For array you can use,
mysql_fetch_array();
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

For objects you can use,
mysql_fetch_object();
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Also , mysql is depricated now from PHP. So you can use PDO / Mysqli

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php